# data not inserted successfully to DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, xampp

- The files saved in htdocs directory
  ** when i run the file i changed it in the url to: localhost/aa.html

html file (aa.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>RegPage</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action ="bb.php" method="post">
name: <input type="text" name "username">
<br/>
email: <input type="text" name ="email">
<br/>
password: <input type="password" name="password">

<input type = "submit" value = "insert">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

php file (bb.php):

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

if(!con)
{
    echo 'not connected to server';
}

if (!mysqli_select_db ($con,'pilot'))
{
    echo 'database not selected';
}

$name=$_post['username'];
$email=$_post['email'];
$password=$_post['password'];

$sql="insert into dbinvestor (email,password,name) values ('$email','$password', '$name')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo 'not inserted';
}
else
{
    echo 'inserted succesfuly';
}

header ("refresh:2;url=aa.html");
?>
```

db and table:
[DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f770.png)

The output:
[OutPut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boJfP.png)

don't know how to solve it,thanks for help !

Comment: `=` is missing on your form `name "username"`. Also `$_POST` must be uppercase.

Comment: @TarangP      email and password - varchar, name - text

Comment: Undefined index `username` that is your error

Comment: @Roms worked, thank you very much :)

Comment: @FireFun365 that fixes part of the problem see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Undefined index `username` should be your error in your php side.

`name: <input type="text" name "username">`

Must be :

`name: <input type="text" name="username">`

Then also use prepared statements on your server side.

Then you also have another error :

`if(!con)`
undefined constant `con`

This should be :

`if(!$con)`

Finally don't store password as plain text use password_hash() and password_verify()

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','');

if(!$con)
{
    echo 'not connected to server';
}

if (!mysqli_select_db ($con,'pilot'))
{
    echo 'database not selected';
}

$name=$_POST['username'];

$email=$_POST['email'];

$password=$_POST['password'];


//hash password

$hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$sql="insert into dbinvestor (email,password,name) values (?,?,?)";


$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_parm("sss",$email,$hash,$name);

if($stmt->execute()){

    echo 'inserted succesfuly';

}else{

    echo 'not inserted';

    echo $stmt->error;
}
?>
```